# How to receive payload per payload on TCP Socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, byte, networkstream

I'm setting up a TCP Client with a network stream that receives payloads from a server, but some times this TCP Clients returns a chunk from the next payload when the server sends a lot of data

I've tried to use `Socket` Class, and `TcpClient` with a `NetworkStream` and the behavior is the same on both

my code looks like this:

```
        TcpClient TcpClient;
        NetworkStream Stream;
        public void Connect_Client()
        {
            TcpClient = new TcpClient(Address, Port);

            Thread thread_Listener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listener));
            thread_Listener.Start();

            Stream = TcpClient.GetStream();
        }

        private void Listener ()
        {
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[2048];
            while (Keep_Running)
            {
               int RecBytes = Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
               int ReminingBytes = RecBytes;
               int NextMsgPos = 0;
               if (RecBytes > 0)
               {
                   char MsgType;
                   while (ReminingBytes > 0)
                   {
                       byte[] BytesMsgLen = new byte[2];
                       BytesMsgLen [1] = Buffer[NextMsgPos];
                       BytesMsgLen [0] = Buffer[NextMsgPos + 1];
                       Int16 MsgLen = BitConverter.ToInt16(BytesMsgLen , 0);
                       byte[] Message = new byte[MsgLen + 2];
                       for(int i = 0; i < MsgLen + 2; i++)
                       {
                           Message[i] = Buffer[i + NextMsgPos];
                       }
                       Process_Message(Message);
                       ReminingBytes = ReminingBytes  - (MsgLen + 2);
                       NextMsgPos = NextMsgPos + MsgLen + 2;
                   }
               }
            }
        }
```

The problem resides in the NextMsgPos calculation because there is ReminingBytes but this ReminingBytes is not an entire Message

I expect that the method .Read() returns an entire payload but some times returns me a payload and a chunk of the next payload

There is any way to guarantee that the network stream returns an entire payload and not a payload + chunk of the next payload?

Comment: Are these packets containing data that tells you how long the data for each payload should be?

Comment: for the entire payload no, the only thing that I know is the MsgLen but I don't know how many messages are in the byte array

Comment: You should use MsgLen in order to find out how many bytes you need in your buffer, then you can use MsgLen to find the entire packet in the buffer. You cant read packet by packet, so you should read for MsgLen, and use MsgLen to locate the whole packet. If you need more help, I can probably help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of "Record" or "Payload" - the TCP Stream is just a Stream. If you have a "Payload" oriented protocol of a fixed number of bytes, or use some kind of header indicating the payload length, you need to code it yourself. Its just the same as reading from a File - a File has no concept of Payload - its a protocol you impose over the raw byte stream.

Comment: There is no header that indicates the payload length, there is just the length of messages, so with this, I can know where is the next one, but the issue comes when a part of the message is on the current received bytes and the other part into the next received bytes

Comment: In which case your problem is one of reading in a specific number of bytes, and retaining those which belong to the "next" record in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at how Redis encoding protocol  [`RESP`](https://redis.io/topics/protocol)  works and make your messages look like that:

Basically as @PhilipH stated you need headers for your payload.

Example , suppose you want to send arrays, strings and integers; you could define them like below:

`[type symbol]` + `[additional data]` + `[ending char(s)]` + `[payload]` +`[ending char(s) ]`

Example:

`Array`:  `*` + `[Length of array in bytes]` +`"\r\n"` 
`Integer`:  `:` + `[Value]` +`"\r\n"` 
`String`:  `$` +`[length of string]`+`"\r\n"`+`[string value]`+`"\r\n"`

So encoding the following array : `["hello",22,"Hi"]` would be:

`*3\r\n$5\r\nhello\r\n:22\r\n$2\r\nhi\r\n`

As you can see each node has a header that specifies what type the payload is and other essential data ( length for strings..etc).

You would then be able to read from your stream chunks of data containing parts from different messages , and act upon them only when encountering the headers.

So suppose you receive :

`[chunk of node 1] [full node 2] [header of node 3]` 
-In this scenario you would have already stored the header of node 1 from your previous chunk so you know what type it is and how it ends.
-You then read node 2 and store it.
-You encounter header of node 3, you store it and wait for your next chunk to fill up node 3.